# Pagecontainer change callback on change

Tags: jquery-mobile

I can't for the life of me figure out how to fire a callback to do something when the page has finished changing.

I have this:

```
  $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#page2", {"transition":"slide"});
```

});

I basically want a function to fire when the page has finished sliding.

This is from the documentation, but it will fire on every page change, rather than on a specific page to page:

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer"  ).pagecontainer({

 change: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the **[transition event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-transition)**

```
$(document).on( "pagecontainertransition", function( event, ui ) {
    if (ui.toPage.prop("id") == "page2") {
      //page2 finished transition, so do something
    }
});
```

Comment: is there anything we can have longer transition time. like smooth sliding.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib - have a look in the jQM CSS file at slide.in, slide.out, etc. You can override the animation-duration property and make it longer than the default 350ms.

Answer (score 0):

To sum it up : rewrite a pagecontainer( "change" ) function with an added callback

```
$.fn.pagecontainerChangeWithCallback = function ( to , option , callback ) {        
    var toClean = to.split('#').join('');
    // listen to transition
    $(document).off( "pagecontainertransition" ).on( "pagecontainertransition", function( event, ui ) {
        // end of "change"
        if ( ui.toPage.prop("id") == toClean && typeof callback == 'function' )
            callback();
    });
    // effective change
    $( "body" ).pagecontainer( "change" , to , option );
    return ( this );
}
```

Usage :

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainerChangeWithCallback( "#page2" , {"transition":"slide"} , function() {
    // my job after transition
});
```